# Android Webview setmediaplaybackrequiresusergesture screen timeout

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, html5-video

I have a HTML5 website including a video (it is not fullscreen). On android side i am using this code to auto play the videos.

```
webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

The problem is the screen timeout is not working whenever i use this code. Is it possible to enable screen timeout while setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture is false?

Comment: What do you mean with "screen timeout"? The delay after which the screen turns off automatically?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Device doesn't enter to the sleep mode.

Comment: I think it's the video playback that stops the screen from entering sleep mode, I don't think you can do a thing against that.

Comment: Thank you! You are true. I just realized that. is it possible to stop the playing video on a broadcast receiver?

Comment: You can inject javascript to start or stop videos if you know the tag of the video in the web page. For instance :             loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()");